# How to change permission of 32GB Memory Card from Read only to read and write?

Tags: permissions

I am trying to copy my data into my memory card using an adapter but my Linux 18.14 LTS is not letting me do it as it shows that the "destination is read-only" I tried most of the ways to resolve my issue but all in vain. what should I do and how can I overcome this issue?
Please Help...

Comment: There are only 12 months in a year, so no 18.14 release of Ubuntu (they are *yy.mm* in format).  Please clarify your release  (*LTS implies to me it's the April release, but given I see 3-5 people a day refer to a non-LTS release as LTS this assumption cannot be made*)

Comment: A read-only file-system usually means the file-system was mounted that way (so remount as rw), OR there are problems with the file-system and it needs a file-system check (`fsck`) which should show in logs (or in messages after the `mount`).

Comment: Standard SD cards (i.e. the huge ones) and micro SD adapters usually have a slider at one side to switch between read-only and read-write mode (which doesn't actually prevent you from writing to it but indicates to the reader that it shouldn't be written to). Is that set to read-write?